# SQL Server 2012 does not display another drive

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I've just installed SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, but it does not display another drive (`D:\`) when I am trying to create new database.

Is there any configuration for display all drive?

Comment: Can the service user that SQL is running under see D:? Can you use a unc path to the drive instead?

Comment: @sasfrog : I'm not getting you. can u elaborate ?

Comment: Well, the instructions you give to SQL management studio, whether through t-SQL or the GUI dialogs, are instructions that get executed by the service account that SQL server is running under. So you're confined to what that account is able to see when deciding for example to create a new database. Hence I'm suggesting you ensure that this account can access and interact with the location you want to deploy the database to.

Comment: "Sql server 2012 does not display..." - Um, SQL Server itself has *no* UI. If you're using Management Studio, *where* in Management Studio are you looking?

Comment: I'm looking in Management Studio...

Comment: Okay, I'll repeat it: "**where** in Management Studio are you looking?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drives that are displayed are relative to the SQL instance that is installed, not the machine that Management Studio is being run on.

So if you have your SQL instance installed on a server that only has one drive, when you connect to it from a remote machine you will only see that one drive.

Comment: if i want to create new database on another drive then what should i do?

Comment: @DharmikBhandari You need to ensure that drive is visible to the machine SQL is installed on - try mapping it to a drive letter.

Comment: Or provide access to MSSQLSERVER account trough the security settings on the drive/folders